# Does AWS provide any IDS/IPS in their services or Suggest some budget friendly 3rd party services

Tags: amazon-web-services, security, amazon-ec2

Looking for budget friendly IDS/IPS for my servers.The time frame would be once in three months. Are there any services i can use to run a test once in 3 months and pay for that particular period of time

Answer (score 1):

There are services like AWS Shield and AWS WAF that you can use for IDS/IPS.

[AWS Shiled](https://aws.amazon.com/shield/)

> AWS Shield is a managed Distributed Denial of Service (DDoS)
>   protection service that safeguards applications running on AWS. AWS
>   Shield provides always-on detection and automatic inline mitigations
>   that minimize application downtime and latency, so there is no need to
>   engage AWS Support to benefit from DDoS protection. There are two
>   tiers of AWS Shield - Standard and Advanced.

[AWS WAF](https://aws.amazon.com/waf/)

> AWS WAF is a web application firewall that helps protect your web
>   applications or APIs against common web exploits that may affect
>   availability, compromise security, or consume excessive resources. AWS
>   WAF gives you control over how traffic reaches your applications by
>   enabling you to create security rules that block common attack
>   patterns, such as SQL injection or cross-site scripting, and rules
>   that filter out specific traffic patterns you define. You can get
>   started quickly using Managed Rules for AWS WAF, a pre-configured set
>   of rules managed by AWS or AWS Marketplace Sellers. The Managed Rules
>   for WAF address issues like the OWASP Top 10 security risks. These
>   rules are regularly updated as new issues emerge. AWS WAF includes a
>   full-featured API that you can use to automate the creation,
>   deployment, and maintenance of security rules.

You can also buy third-party software that you can run on EC2 instances for IDS/IPS.

[Intrusion Detection & Prevention Systems](https://aws.amazon.com/mp/scenarios/security/ids/)

> EC2 Instance IDS/IPS solutions offer key features to help protect your
>   EC2 instances. This includes alerting administrators of malicious
>   activity and policy violations, as well as identifying and taking
>   action against attacks. You can use AWS services and third party
>   IDS/IPS solutions offered in AWS Marketplace to stay one step ahead of
>   potential attackers.

Comment: Aws shield and waf are real time protections right ? , My use case is i need to run a vulnerability and penetration testing once in three months. Which services in your point of view is ideal for my use case

Comment: Penetration testing on web interface? If that's the case both WAF and Shiled are good.

Comment: But if you want to protect at the servers level then get one of the third party softwares avaialbke on the AWS market palce

Comment: Can You suggest some,

Comment: Click on the link in the answer